# How do I customise the IFD login page for MSCRM 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, adfs, dynamics-crm-2016

I have Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 installed on-premise.

I wish to customise the IFD login page. I have searched on the internet but have been unable to find a resource to help me.

Specifically I want to change the Microsoft copyright notice highlighted below.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Before you upload the onload.js to ADFS put following text at the end of script:

```
document.getElementById('copyright').innerHTML='&#169;Copyright 2016'
```

this will change Copyright text to text behind the in `' '` behind the `=`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can change sections of the page using PowerShell commands [Customizing the AD FS Sign-in Pages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950(v=ws.11).aspx).

If those commands can't do what you can add JavaScript functions to edit the page. [Advanced Customization of AD FS Sign-in Pages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636121(v=ws.11).aspx).

```
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName custom -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri=’/adfs/portal/script/onload.js’;path="c:\theme\script\onload.js"}
```

Comment: Thanks @James Wood.. i saw this links but any thing in this page can not help me...
also i change the onload.js but every thing in my customization until now had gone.